# RSpec - How to test the keys and values of response header?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, http-headers, response

I'm adding the configuration API in my Rails to use GZIP compression and is working, but I've trouble with the rspec.

**config.ru**:

```
use Rack::Deflater
```

**application.rb**:

```
config.middleware.use Rack::Deflater
```

**users_controller_spec.rb**:

```
context "GZIP" do
    it "produces an identical eTag whether content is deflated or not" do
      get :users, format: 'json', 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'=>"Token token=\"#{user.token}\""

      expect(response.headers).to have_key("Content-Length")
      expect(response.headers).to have_key("Etag")
      expect(response.headers).to_not have_key("Content-Encoding")
      expect(response.headers["Content-Encoding"]).to be_nil

      etag = response.headers["Etag"]
      content_length = response.headers["Content-Length"].to_i

      get :users, format: 'json', 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'=>"Token token=\"#{user.token}\"", "HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" => "gzip"

      expect(response.headers["Etag"]).to eql(etag)
      expect(response.headers["Content-Length"].to_i).to be < content_length
      expect(response.headers).to have_key("Content-Encoding")
      expect(response.headers["Content-Encoding"]).to eql("gzip")
    end
  end
```

The spec failed when I tested the keys on response.headers. I think my response haven't any keys. But when I tested in my browser I see this result in **Response Headers**:

```
Cache-Control:max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
ETag:"e45c1e970b7fb10b35c9acf52bfb64e7"
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-Request-Id:04ae0c72-21e5-4ada-bdf3-63d2815254f0
X-Runtime:0.734614
X-UA-Compatible:chrome=1
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

Is there any way to test the keys and values of response header? What did I miss?

Thank you.